# Javascript checkbox values

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code, that substracts from a total sum, a value when a checkbox is checked. In my case for each checkbox checked it substracts 20.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function Calculate(){
    var tag = window.document.getElementsByClassName("hsnb"), total = <? echo $total; ?>;
    for (var i in tag){
        total -= tag[i].checked && !isNaN(Number(20)) ? Number(20) : 0;
    }
    var cucu = + total.toFixed(2);

    if(cucu < "20"){  
        alert("You dont have enough points!");
        for(i = 1; document.getElementById("bifa" + i) !== null; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById("bifa" + i).checked){

            } else {
                document.getElementById("bifa" + i).disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    window.document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = '<span style="font-size:20px;">You have: POINTS' + cucu + '</span>';
}​
</script>
```

I want to give each checkbox a certain value, let's say:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" value="10">
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" value="20">
```

And if i check the first checkbox it should substract 10 and if i check the second checkbox substract 20. You know what i mean, substract the value for each checkbox. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I strongly recommend using a good JavaScript framework for this type of work, to make your code more readable and easier to write.  I like Dojo; many people love jQuery.  Do you want radios instead of checkboxes, or can multiple subtractions apply?   You can add an onChange event to each checkbox, which subtracts (or returns) the appropriate amount for each change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you should try using jQuery, something like

```
var sub = 0;
jQuery("input[name=check]:checked").each(function(index, element){
    sub = sub + jQuery(element).val();
});
var total = yourNumber - sub;
```

I'haven't tested this snippet but it should work

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In plain javascript you can attach an event to each input an check the "checked" property each time the handler is invoked; if true then substract the input value from the total sum:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" value="10">
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" value="20">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            var aBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), iTotal = <? echo $total; ?>;
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(aBox,function(oCheck, iIdx,aBox){
                oCheck.onclick = function(){
                    if(this.checked){
                        iTotal = iTotal - this.value;
                        console.log(iTotal);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```